# How to show output for group of people instead of single individual?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written this code to show the FEE PAID, PENDING etc for an individual student but actually it was supposed to be for the whole class of students. I tried a lot but can't do it for the whole class. How to do this ? Ignore @studentID, I just want it for @ClassID.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Accounts].[GetUserPaymentsPartialRecord] 
    @StudentId INT= 14,
    @classID int=1 
AS
BEGIN



    declare @accID int
    set @accID= (select st.Account_ID from School.StudentInformation ST where st.StudentID = @StudentId and st.ClassToWhichAdmitted_ID= @classID)

    declare @className varchar(50)
    Set @className= (Select c.ClassName from School.Classes c 
                     Inner Join School.StudentInformation si 
                     ON si.ClassToWhichAdmitted_ID= c.ClassID where si.StudentID= @StudentId) 

    declare @transactions varchar(max)
    Set @transactions=(select convert(varchar,Convert(decimal(10,0),t.Credit))+', ' AS 'data()'  from Accounts.Transactions T 
    where t.Account_ID = (@accID)
    and
    t.Credit>0 
    AND 
    t.IsReversed=0
    AND 
    t.InvoiceNumber in(Select inv.InvoiceNumber from Accounts.Invoices inv where inv.Student_ID= @StudentId) 
    AND 
    Particulars Like '%Received%'
    FOR XML PATH(''))

    declare @PayableAmount money
    set @PayableAmount = (select sum(i.Amount+ i.Fine) from Accounts.Invoices I where I.Student_ID= @StudentId and i.Class_ID = @classID )              


    declare @TotalAmountPaid money
    Set @TotalAmountPaid= (Select sum(t.Credit) from Accounts.Transactions T 
    where t.Account_ID = (@accID)
    and
    t.Credit>0 
    AND 
    t.IsReversed=0 
    AND 
    t.InvoiceNumber in(Select inv.InvoiceNumber from Accounts.Invoices inv where inv.Student_ID= @StudentId) 
    AND 
    t.Particulars Like '%Received%'
    group by t.Account_ID)


    declare @PendingAmount money
    Set @PendingAmount= (@PayableAmount - @TotalAmountPaid)

    SELECT st.StudentName, st.StudentRegisterationNo,@className as ClassName, 
            @transactions as Paid, Convert(decimal(10,0),@TotalAmountPaid) as TotalPaid,
            @PayableAmount, @PendingAmount as 'PendingAmount' FROM School.StudentInformation ST 
    where st.StudentID= @StudentId



END
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also check [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the above procedure which is at student and class level to simply as a tabular set which can be queried at class level

See sample proc below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Accounts].[GetUserPaymentsPartialRecordByClass] 
   @classID int=1 
AS
BEGIN

create table #temp (sID int,cID int, accID int, className varchar(50),transactions varchar(max),PayableAmount money,TotalAmountPaid money,PendingAmount money)

INSERT into #temp
    (sID,cID,accID,className)
select 
    distinct st.StudentID as sID, 
    st.ClassToWhichAdmitted_ID as cID ,
    st.Account_ID as accID, 
    c.ClassName as className
from School.StudentInformation st
    left join School.Classes c 
        on st.ClassToWhichAdmitted_ID= c.ClassID 
where st.ClassToWhichAdmitted_ID= @classID

update temp
set temp.transactions=transactions
from #temp temp outer apply(
select convert(varchar,Convert(decimal(10,0),t.Credit))+', ' AS 'data()'
from Accounts.Transactions T 
on T.Account_ID=temp.accID
and T.Credit>0 and T.IsReversed=0 
and Particulars Like '%Received%'
inner join Accounts.Invoices inv
on inv.Student_ID=temp.sID and inv.InvoiceNumber=T.InvoiceNumber
FOR XML PATH('')
) s(transactions)




update T
set PayableAmount =  sum(i.Amount+ i.Fine) 
from #temp T 
INNER JOIN Accounts.Invoices I ON I.Student_ID= T.sId and i.Class_ID = T.cID             

update temp
set TotalAmountPaid =sum(t.Credit) from 
#temp temp Inner join
Accounts.Transactions T 
on t.Account_ID = temp.accID
and t.Credit>0 AND t.IsReversed=0 and
t.Particulars Like '%Received%'
inner join Accounts.Invoices inv
on inv.Student_ID=temp.sID and inv.InvoiceNumber=T.InvoiceNumber
group by T.Account_ID


update temp
sett PendingAmount= (PayableAmount - TotalAmountPaid)

SELECT st.StudentName, st.StudentRegisterationNo,ClassName, 
    transactions as Paid, Convert(decimal(10,0),TotalAmountPaid) as TotalPaid,
    PayableAmount, PendingAmount as 'PendingAmount' FROM #temp T inner join School.StudentInformation ST 
    On st.StudentID= T.sId



END
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetUserPaymentsPartialRecordByClass, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetUserPaymentsPartialRecordByClass, Line 50
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.